# How many combinations of $3$ natural numbers are there that add up to $30$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions, natural-numbers, permutations

How many combinations of $3$ natural numbers are there that add up to $30$?

The answer is $75$ but I need the approach.

Although I know that we can use $_{(n-1)}C_{(r-1)}$ i.e. $_{29}C_2 = 406$ but this is when $a, b, c$ are distinguishable which is not the case here.

Please explain.

EDIT
three such examples:  
$\begin{align}
1+1+28 \\
10+10+10 \\
1+2+27 \\
...
\end{align}$

Comment: People are sensitive to "all caps" in this website, they say it is shouting, but I guess you did not intend that way.

Comment: Please change the ALL CAPS title and initial sentence. Also, your question doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: Don't complain - [Edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/453661/edit)! (From the [help centre](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing), "(This) site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!")

Comment: I think is $\dbinom{32}{2}=492$ when numbers are distinguishable.

Comment: It's still difficult to tell what you're asking. Are you saying that these three natural numbers have to add up to $30$?

Comment: @Ataraxia; thanks for your respnse, yes I am asking about the number of ways in which three natural numbers can add up to 30, I will edit the question as well to make it more clear.
I am preparing for an exam actually and derivation of formula is not required. Although it is based upon the following and I am familiar with the concept as well
[link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(probability)

Comment: You are looking for the partitions into $3$  (not necessarily distinct) non-zero parts. A quick semi-listing does give $75$.

Comment: I edited to better reflect what you're asking for. If you don't like, feel free to roll it back :)

Comment: Are you considering 0 a natural number?

Comment: Do you know how to apply burnsides lemme to deal with the fact that you want to count without repetition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ideas of this method is known as burnsides lemma in group theory.

As you pointed out, the number of positive integer solutions to $a+b+c=30$ is ${29 \choose 2}=406$ by the stars and bars. However it over counts the total because the numbers are indistinguishable.

How many times does it over count? If all the numbers are the same, I.e. $a=b=c$, then there is just one way.

If two of the numbers are equal, then $2a+c=30$, and there are 14 ways corresponding to $a=1$ to 14. However we would double count $a=b=c$ so there are 13 ways. Each of these 13 ways would lead to 39 ways if the numbers were indistinguishable.

Now, of the 406 distinguished ways, lets subtract off the $1+39=40$ distinguished ways listed above, giving us 366. These correspond to distinct a, b, c values. Each of these ways are counted 6 times. Hence there are $366/6=61$ undistinguished ways.

Now we add back the 13 undistinguished from the two same one different, and the 1 undistinguished from three same, and we get $61+13+1=75$

Comment: Hmm, why do we take 2 out of 29, instead of 3 out of 30?

Answer (score 3):

If we want the answer to a small problem like this, we can list systematically and count.

We only count the number of partitions of $30$ into $3$ parts.  The same idea can be used to produce an explicit formula for the number of partitions of $n$ into $3$ parts. For one notices a simple pattern. If we want $4$ parts, a similar idea works. In principle what we use below is a recurrence, from the easy $2$ parts to the less easy $3$ parts.

We make a list by smallest element in the partition:

Smallest $10$: $1$ way

Smallest $9$: $2$ ways.

Smallest $8$: $4$ ways (next one is $8$ to $11$)

Smallest $7$: $5$ ways

Smallest $6$: $7$ ways (next one $6$ to $12$)

Smallest $5$: $8$ ways

Smallest $4$: $10$ ways.

Smallest $3$: $11$ ways

Smallest $2$: $13$ ways

Smallest $1$: $14$ ways (next one $1$ to $14$)

Note the nice pattern of increase of the numbers. Now add.

**Another way:** The following is another direct computational approach. Let $f(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $3$ parts. The smallest part can be (i) greater than $1$ or (ii) equal to $1$.

In Case (i), by removing a $1$ from each part, we get a partition of $n-3$, and we get all partitions of $n-3$ in this way.

To count the Case (ii) possibilities, note that we must partition $n-1$ into two parts. If $n-1$ is odd , this can be done in $(n-2)/2$ ways. If $n-1$ is even it can be done in $(n-1)/2$ ways.

So we have obtained the recurrence
$f(n)=f(n-3)+(n-2)/2$ if $n$ is even, and $f(n)=f(n-3)+(n-1)/2$ if $n$ is odd.

Armed with this recurrence, we can to $n=30$ quickly by $3$'s from the base case $n=3$.

Comment: Why are 3, 6, 9, and 12 ways missing?

Comment: Imagine listing the partitions as $(a,b,c)$ where $a\ge b\ge c$. If smallest is $9$, then $b$ can only be $9$ or $10$. If the smallest is $8$, then $b$ can be $8$ or $9$ or $10$ or $11$. Basically the reason for the jump is that $30-3$ is odd but $30-4$ is even.  You  will notice a jump of $2$ at the evens.

Comment: If the question were 4 numbers adding to 30, would 4,8,12 be missing?

Comment: I have not thought about it.  There would be some funny stuff happening at multiples of $3$.  For the simpler problem of partitioning say $60$ into $3$ parts, I am sure you can use the same template to find the answer. We would do the final summing by formula.

Answer (score 0):

First, I say +1 to Calvin and Andre, nice solutions.

This is covered in the theory of partitions. The use of generating functions is helpful. Not only do they remove the problem of over counting but they generate a sequence of answers which has value that will be seen later.

The generating function for a partition of a number into 3 positive parts is given by

$$G(x) = \frac{x^3}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$$

the theory is given in https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf  number (2)

You only need to determine the coefficient of $x^{30}$. The simplest way to do so is  to take it to Wolfram Alpha and enter "Series[x^3/((1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)),{x,0,30}]" then check the coefficient of $x^{30}$, it will be 75. If you need to, the whole computation can be done by hand using polynomial multiplication or by other methods discussed on this forum.

You should notice that the polynomial spit out by Alpha contains other coefficients. These are the answers to 3 part partitions summing to 29, 28, 27 ...

Taking the coefficients as a sequence we can now enter 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 19 at the OEIS be sent here http://oeis.org/A069905 and see what is currently known about this sequence of which your problem is a part.